# RLE encoding, how do I figure out how many symbols do I have after RLE has done its part?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, b, c, s = 0, ks = 0, m = 0, count[300] = {0};
    char str[300];
    float kompr;
    scanf("%s", str);
    c = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i < c;)
    { 
        b = 0;
        count[i] = 1;
        do
        {
            b++;
            if (str[i + b] == str[i])
            {
                count[i]++;
            }
        } while (str[i + b] == str[i]);

        {
            if (count[i] <= 2)
            {
                printf("%C",str[i++]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%C%d", str[i], count[i]);
                i += count[i];
      
                m--;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: Invalid input!");
            return 100;
        }
        s++;
        ks = s + m;
    }
    kompr = (float)ks / s;
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Input Symbols: %d\n", s);
    fprintf(stderr,"Coded Symbols: %d\n", ks);
    fprintf(stderr,"Compresion Ratio: %.2f\n", kompr);

    return 0;
}
```

Idea is this
Input:AAAABCCD
Output:A4BCCD
Stderr:Input Symbols:8
Coded Symbols:6
Compresion Ratio:0,25

I tried decrementing after each operation but that wont work most of the times only in very specific cases, so my idea is if I could read the number of current symbols I wouldn't have to decrement anything, but I have no clue how.

```
fprintf(stderr,"Input Symbols: %d\n",  
printf("%C%d",str[i],count[i]));
```

why does this not work?
this return value just goes on 2 no matter what I input

Comment: You tried decrementing _what_? And why won't it work?

Comment: I made variable "m=0" and decremented it after each encoding then I added "m" to number of symbols which doesnt work for large texts, basicaly if you input SSSH it would decrement by one while outputing S3H but when you would input SSSSSH it would decrement only once because there is only one operation which is making SSSSS into S5, this means I only get a value of -1 even tho I need -3 because the text is now only 3 symbols long ("S5H")

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is, but `printf` has a return value - maybe that would be of use to you.

Comment: would it return how many characters are in printf ?

Comment: [yes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: noice thx mate.

Comment: doesnt work too bad, works well for the string but doesnt work for this  printf("%C%d", str[i], count[i])

Comment: For RLE, with input `AAAABCCD`, I think you want output of `A4BC2D`

Comment: @CraigEstey It depends how the threshold is set. Since "CC" uses as many characters as "C2", there is no compression, so it might be decided to leave it uncompressed.

Answer (score 0):

When you *tried decrementing after each operation* you had a feasible approach of accumulating the savings of the compression - you just didn't decrement by the correct number in cases where the number is different from one. The correct number is the difference between the original length, which is `count[i]`, and the compressed length, which is the result of the `printf("%C%d", str[i], count[i])`, so you can change

```
                printf("%C%d", str[i], count[i]);
                i += count[i];
      
                m--;
```

to

```
                m -= count[i] -
                printf("%C%d", str[i], count[i]);
                i += count[i];
```